# How can I use the check testing framework from Clion and Cmake?

Tags: c, unit-testing, clion

I use the check testing framework to unit test my C code. The test when it's run looks like this.

```
$ checkmk tst_bquotes.check > bquotes-test.c
dac@dac-Latitude-E7450:~/kth/os/lab3/openshell$ gcc -Wall -o bquotes-test util.c errors.c bquotes-test.c -lcheck -lsubunit -lrt -pthread -lm
dac@dac-Latitude-E7450:~/kth/os/lab3/openshell$ ./bquotes-test 
Running suite(s): Core
100%: Checks: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0
```

How can I add this test to my cmake build script?

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0)
project(shell.test)

if (EDITLINE_LIBRARIES AND EDITLINE_INCLUDE_DIRS)
    set(Editline_FIND_QUIETLY TRUE)
endif (EDITLINE_LIBRARIES AND EDITLINE_INCLUDE_DIRS)

find_path(EDITLINE_INCLUDE_DIRS NAMES editline/readline.h)
find_library(EDITLINE_LIBRARIES NAMES edit)

include(FindPackageHandleStandardArgs)
FIND_PACKAGE_HANDLE_STANDARD_ARGS(Editline DEFAULT_MSG
        EDITLINE_LIBRARIES
        EDITLINE_INCLUDE_DIRS)

mark_as_advanced(EDITLINE_INCLUDE_DIRS EDITLINE_LIBRARIES)

set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} -L/usr/local/include/ -L/usr/include -std=gnu99 -pedantic-errors -O3 -g -Wall -pedantic -ledit -ltermcap")
include_directories(/usr/local/include/ /usr/include)
link_directories(/usr/lib)
link_directories(/usr/local/lib)
add_executable(shell main.c errors.c util.c shellparser.c)
target_link_libraries(shell edit readline)
add_custom_target(shellparser DEPENDS ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/shellparser.c)
add_custom_command(OUTPUT ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/shellparser.c COMMAND lemon -s ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/shellparser.y DEPENDS ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/shellparser.y)
add_dependencies(shell shellparser)
```

My project structure looks like:

```
$ tree
.
├── bquotes-test
├── bquotes-test.c
├── CMakeLists.txt
├── CommandEntry.h
├── do.h
├── errors.c
├── errors.h
├── integrationtest.sh
├── lemon.c
├── lempar.c
├── LICENSE
├── main.c
├── Makefile
├── openshell.h
├── README.md
├── shellparser.c
├── shellparser.h
├── shellparser.out
├── shellparser.y
├── stresstest.sh
├── tst_bquotes.check
├── tst_exp.sh
├── types.h
├── unittest.sh
└── util.c

0 directories, 25 files
```

My check test is

```
#include "openshell.h"
#include "errors.h"
#test myQtest
fail_unless(isBetweenQuotes(11, "abc'asdqerfdsdxcvc'xc") == 1, "isBetweenQuotes function borked");
fail_unless(isBetweenQuotes(5, "This has no quotes") == 0, "isBetweenQuotes2 function borked");
fail_unless(isBetweenQuotes(11, "This' is a sentence in 'quotes") == 1, "isBetweenQuotes3 function borked");
fail_unless(isBetweenQuotes(15, "\"This is a sentence in quotes\"") == 1, "isBetweenQuotes4 function borked");
/* gcc -Wall -o bquotes-test util.c errors.c bquotes-test.c -lcheck -lsubunit -lrt -pthread -lm */
/* checkmk tst_bquotes.check > bquotes-test.c */
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try this. Create an external linux shell script, which has the line

```
checkmk tst_bquotes.check > bquotes-test.c
```

in it and call it something like prepare_test.sh. Then, I would add these lines to your `CMakeLists.txt` at the end:

```
execute_process(
    COMMAND ./prepare_test.sh 
    WORKING_DIRECTORY ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR} 
    RESULT_VARIABLE prep_test_result)

add_executable(bquotes-test util.c errors.c bquotes-test.c )
target_link_libraries(bquotes-test check subunit rt pthread m)

add_test(start_test_bquotes bquotes-test)
include(CTest)
```

After you've called `cmake`, you can then start the tests with `make test`.